# use octal characters on multi line strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to read a .csv file and create a multiline string for each data entry. Each entry needs to get written to a .xml file.

Each entry has a predefined format which is

[image]

https://pastebin.com/RyT31gJX

This is what I have so far

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const csv = require('fast-csv');

const { csvPath, delimiter } = require('./config.json');

fs.createReadStream(csvPath)
.pipe(csv({ delimiter }))
.on('data', data => {
    const login = data[0];
    const firstname = data[1];
    const lastname = data[2];
    const internal = data[3]; // 49....
    const convertedInternal = internal.slice(2); // remove the 49 from the phonenumber

    // create a multiline string that's gets written to a .xml file
    const xmlEntry = `
    sip isdn    t:${login}  g:Avaya (.*)    +${internal}    (.*)    \1  from_pstn_src_setting=
    isdn    sip g:Avaya p:${login}  (.*)    \1  0${convertedInternal}   \1  
    `;
})
.on('end',() => {
    // done
});
```

When executing the code I get the error

> SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.

How can I fix it?

Then required multiline string format is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `String.raw` instead, which will interpret the string exactly as typed (plus interpolated variables):

```
const xmlEntry = String.raw`
    sip isdn    t:${login}  g:Avaya (.*)    +${internal}    (.*)    \1  from_pstn_src_setting=
    isdn    sip g:Avaya p:${login}  (.*)    \1  0${convertedInternal}   \1  
`;
```

Or, of course, double-escape the backslashes so they aren't interpreted as octal escapes:

```
const xmlEntry = `
    sip isdn    t:${login}  g:Avaya (.*)    +${internal}    (.*)    \\1  from_pstn_src_setting=
    isdn    sip g:Avaya p:${login}  (.*)    \\1  0${convertedInternal}   \\1  
`;
```